# RxJava Function with more than nine arguments

Tags: rx-java

I'm running some benchmarks, and I require functions with up to 16 arguments. RxJava defines Function[1-9], and FunctionN. How can I create a function with more than nine arguments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use `FunctionN`? For java it's `FuncN`. Just pass the 16 arguments and it will work just fine.

```
public interface FuncN<R> extends Function {
    public R call(Object... args);
}
```

Source code for `Func9`

```
public interface Func9<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, R> extends Function {
    public R call(T1 t1, T2 t2, T3 t3, T4 t4, T5 t5, T6 t6, T7 t7, T8 t8, T9 t9);
}
```

If you really need `Func10` to `Func16` implement every function on your own:

```
public interface Func10<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, R> extends Function {
    public R call(T1 t1, T2 t2, T3 t3, T4 t4, T5 t5, T6 t6, T7 t7, T8 t8, T9 t9, T10 t10);
}
```